# What is the difference between jboss.jms and jboss.mq ?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, message-queue, jboss-messaging

What is the difference between the classes *org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService* and *org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService` is part of JBossMessaging, which is JBoss's new JMS implementation, supplied as part of JBoss AppServer version 5 and later (or JBoss EAP 4.3 or later)

`org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue` is part of JBossMQ, which is part of JBoss's old (and now obsolete) JMS implementation, found in JBoss AppServer versions up to 4.2

Answer (score 2):

JBoss Messaging will be replaced by [JBoss HornetQ](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HornetQGeneralFAQs):

> HornetQ takes over from JBoss
>   Messaging as our premier JMS
>   implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know JBossMQ will be replaced by JBoss Messaging in JBoss AS 5.0.

For further details see:

[Notice 1](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/jbossmq) and related topic [Related Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507391/active-mq-vs-jboss-messaging)